# I am new in Android development, when I want to add color to my xml file, say @color/white, I am told, "cannot resolve the symbol @color/white"

Tags: android, kotlin

This is my code sample;

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
android:background="@color/white"
>
```

[You can see that the error is red](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xh3BS.png)

Comment: Have you added `<color name="white">#FFFFFF</color>` in `strings.xml`?

Comment: Can you show your folder structure ?

Comment: You can't reference what hasn't been created.

Comment: Thanks guys for the prompt answers . I'm glad you guys are there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to navigate to **res -> values -> colors.xml** file [check pic here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sIlaq.jpg) and add the following code their:

```
<color name="white">#ffffff</color>
```

Or you can directly use this code in linear layout

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
android:background="#ffffff"<!--Change color according to need this is for white-->
>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also just change it to:

```
android:background="@android:color/white"
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to change linear layout color in white!?? as already it is white color!?

Comment: Well, I'm following a tutorial from somewhere. Like I did mention, I am new in the programming world and can't yet tell why things are done the way they are done. Thanks for the idea though.

Comment: I can understand you but I can suggest you to learn from w3schools, tutorial points,and medium websites and more obviously our Android devops website to learn from basics.. even I had done the same..

Comment: Okay, any other proposals aside from w3shools?

Comment: I think you can follow this  https://medium.com/  , https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/  , https://www.tutorialspoint.com/index.htm, https://developer.android.com/